# Installing XP sp3 on a limited hardware

Tags: windows, installation, boot

I have a HP t5740 (Atom processor, 1GB ram, 2GB flash HDD). I got it pre-installed with XP sp2 so I downloaded the new service pack from MS website but it said it didn't have enough disk space to perform the installation.

But according to the system requirements it only needs about 1.5GB so I guess that was some extra working space. So I got XP installation with SP3 integrated and tried to install that. Since it only has one 44pin ATA port (where the flash HDD is), a network plug and few USBs my options were limited. I made an install flash disk using flashboot and it all went fine until it couldn't copy setuporg.exe. The image itself is fine since it worked in a VM.

So, what are my next options? I will try to make a boot usb drive from another image but that still limits me to 2GB. Getting a bigger internal is not an option (limited suppliers, not in stock, ...). Should I attach a bigger external USB drive? If so, will selecting booting from USB in bios work if I have external drive and an install flash disk? Will I need to do a network install? Some other way?

(Note: I know 2GB is really a little space and it should run embedded XP, but I really only need a few hundred MB after I have SP3 on there so unless necessary I don't want to replace the flash HDD. Also it's mounted in a corner with very little space and some replacements I found online won't even fit.)

Answer (score 0):

After SP3 is fully installed it may as we take up 1.5GB of space but it unpacks a load of tempaoary files that could take up more space than you have. It might be possible to put the installer on a USB stick so it "unpacks" to the USB stick rather than the 2GB internal flash. I would not really try to put a fully updated Windowx XP on a small disk, in my virtual machines a full Win XP install clocks in at around 10GB.

Either try using something like [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) to "slim down" the instillation, or try an alternative OS such as Ubuntu if possible. I would reccomend, however, contacing HP and see if they offer any other disks.

Comment: I was installing the SP3 from a stick so that won't work. Now I have a formatted HDD with failed install so I need to fix the USB boot. I'm leaving new HDD as a last option since I need it fast and that takes time.